# Как на golang транслировать видео в поток?

Tags: golang, потоки-данных, streaming, online-video

Нужно сделать видеоконференцию на golang.
Суть- просто подлкючаются люди к комнате из браузера и их изображение транслируется на сервер и затем другим людям.
Есть ли примеры на golang?
Спасибо

Comment: А к этому видеосерверу будут подключаться аппаратные кодеки для видеоконференций, видеофоны, SIP-клиенты и так далее? Или только браузер?

Comment: @gbg ну для начала(и я думаю- только так и будет) только браузер, но если есть ещё примеры- подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: вы пытаетесь совместить в одном решении две сущности. Дело в том, что существует деление на MCU - собственно сервер, который микширует потоки и обеспечивает связность, и Terminal - клиентская часть. То есть, у вашем случае, Terminal - это браузер.


Так вот - MCU уже готовый есть, это openmcu-ru. Это решение прекрасно трудится у меня на продакшене. 

Так что вам нужно только обеспечить работу терминальной стороны, мост из webRTC в SIP. И такое решение тоже есть - Linphone-Web.